# 'Debugger for Firefox' VSCode Extension shows error 'cannot find profile development'

Tags: visual-studio-code, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When launching firefox through a VSCode debug configuration, an error message appears: `cannot find profile development` and firefox doesn't launch. This is in a WSL remote window with Ubuntu 22.04. Firefox Developer Edition is installed on the host. It doesn't have a profile called 'development'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `about:profiles` in Firefox (type that into the address bar and go to that page) and create a new profile called `development`.